# Well-tried and tested Windows batch file stops at for loop since today - what could be the cause?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, crash

I have written and used a windows batch file that has been working without a problem for quite a while.
This is what it does:
The program loops through the *.pdf files of the current folder, and then performs a few tasks like extracting the text layer of the pdf file, searching for a couple of search terms and in the end it renames the pdf file according to which search term was found.
The batch file worked fine until today.
Now it just stops working at the for loop and I have no idea why.
Stripped down to the essence, the batch looks like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *.pdf') do (
   echo %%i
   echo %%~ti
   echo %%~ni
   )
```

The echos would just be examples, but as the batch files never reaches what's after the for loop, I simplified it.
Since today, the program would just stop when it reaches the for loop.

This is what I tried to solve the problem:

- examined the syntax of the for loop, found no mistakes
- tried simplified variations of the for /f loop including leaving out the delims option, changing it against a usebackq option, changing the name of the loop variable, stripping down the options of the dir command, changing the file filter to *.txt
- turned the for loop into a one-liner with just an echo %%i command etc.
- looped through the lines of a given text file
- changed the location of the batch file to another folder
- tried the batch on a Windows 10 and a Windows 7 system
- try again after rebooting the system
- checked folder access rights, I had all of them, no restrictions

None of these helped, the batch file would always stop and close its window right at the for loop.

- I also inserted the dir command before the for loop just to check the syntax - this worked with no problem, so it can't be the syntax of the dir command either.

I remember that I had this problem a few times years ago and it either disappeared by itself or I had to retype the batch word for word in a new text file copying whatever was in the original file as copy and paste wouldn't work.

Has anyone out there observed this strange behaviour and maybe found the cause and at best a solution for it? I'd be so thrilled.

EDIT: When I run the batch in the cmd window, I get a simple SYNTAX ERROR when it reaches the line with the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure that you've saved this code as an ANSI file, not as Unicode?

Comment: I tried versions saved as ANSI as well as Unicode and UTF-8. It made no difference. I thought this would only affect printing special characters or can it also mess up the program?

Comment: When you don't start it per mouseclick, but open a `cmd` window and start the batch from there - is there any message?

Comment: Stephan, from a cmd window, it returns a syntax error in the for loop. Interesting. But where is the error?

Comment: Are there for sure no special characters (like typographical quotation marks or apostrophes rather than straight ones, non-break spaces rather than normal ones, etc.)? What line-breaks are there (CR, LF, or CR+LF)?

Comment: @aschipfl looking at the code via Notepad++ I couldn't find any special character and every line ends with a CR+LF.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message and everything after that into the question, please?

Comment: What happens on the command line, if you try `FOR /F %X in ('echo test') do echo out: %X` and does it work if you copy only `FOR /F %%X in ('echo test') do echo out: %%X` into a batch file? Btw. If you tried the same file on Win10 and Win7, then there are invalid characters in the batch file. I would type a new simple test file, don't copy&paste

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the command prompt:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```

Both results should be empty, but probably in your case they are set.
The problem of the AutoRun file, it's started when a new cmd instance is started, but also for the FOR/F command.

If this is the problem, you should delete these entries by

```
reg DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
reg DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

Or if you really need an AutoRun batch, then it should start with a guard.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM *** ALWAYS make a copy of the complete CMDCMDLINE, else you destroy the originial!!!
set "_ccl_=!cmdcmdline!"

REM *** The check is necessary to distinguish between a new cmd.exe instance for a user or for a "FOR /F" sub-command
if "!_ccl_:~1,-2!" == "!comspec!" (
    REM ***** INTERACTIVE ****
    REM *** Do your stuff ***
)
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks for going in so deep, @jeb. I checked via command prompt and regedit. Unfortunately, no AutoRun keys could be found.